# ORA-00926: missing VALUES keyword while using insert into table as select * from in execute immediate

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

I have two table emp1 and emp2 i want to create emp3 by using emp1 and emp2 all this i need to do plsql to automate code

I tried coding but getting

> ORA-00926: missing VALUES keyword ORA-06512: at line 9

```
declare
v1  varchar2(2000);
begin 
for i in 1..2
loop
v1:='insert into emp3 as select * from emp'||i||'where 1=1;';
execute immediate v1;
end loop;
end;
```

ORA-00926: missing VALUES keyword
ORA-06512: at line 9.
i have a bigger where condition but i just used 'where 1=1' and bigger tables but i need the logic for this thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First, I don't think there is any `as`.

Second, if you printed out the sql, the problem would probably be obvious.

You can try this:

```
insert into emp3 
    select * from emp'||i||' where 1=1;'
```

Comment: declare
v1  varchar2(2000);
begin 
for i in 1..2
loop
v1:='insert into emp3  select * from emp'||i||' where 1=1';
execute immediate v1;
end loop;
end;   i compiled this

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic SQL is hard because it turns compilation errors into runtime errors. For instance, in this case you are missed the leading space before the `where`:

```
v1:='insert into emp3 as select * from emp'||i||'where 1=1;';
------------------------------------------------^
```

This means the actual SQL your code attempts to execute is

```
insert into emp3 as select * from emp1where 1=1;
```

Which is not valid SQL and that's why you get an error.

The other mistake is we don't need to include the terminating character at the end of the string. So the correct code should be

```
v1:='insert into emp3 as select * from emp'||i||' where 1=1';
```

In future you should use include code to display the dynamic statement. You are halfway there by assigning the statement to a variable before executing it. So you just need to log it, which could be as simple as

```
dbms_output.put_line(v1);
```

It's a lot easier to spot bloomers in the assembled string than it is to try to interpret the concatenation of boilerplate and variables.